# Rails 4 Make Default for f select null

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, drop-down-menu

I want to make the default option for my dropdown select in a form null. I added

```
{:include_blank => true}
```

but the initial blank option is not showing up.

Here's the line of code:

```
<%= f.select :user_ids, options_for_select(User.all.collect{|user| [user.name, user.id]}, @reservation.user_ids), {multiple: true, :class=>'user-id-widget', size: 5}, {:include_blank => true} %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [**`select`**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select),you need to write `:include_blank => true` as an argument of `html_options`

This should work

```
<%= f.select :user_ids, options_for_select(User.all.collect{|user| [user.name, user.id]}, @reservation.user_ids), {multiple: true, :include_blank => true,:class=>'user-id-widget', size: 5} %>
```